# Wordpress Permalink issue on subdirectory wordpress

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, blogs, permalinks

I have installed wordpress inside one folder called blog. when we open the blog, the blog links are broken 404 page error. How do i fix this issue, if its installed on root directory it will work, but this time it is directory, Is there any way to fix this issue

Answer (score 0):

Normally such issues can be fixed easily by refreshing your permalinks. To do that go to WP > Settings > Permalinks and click on the save button once.

On some servers it is not allowed to edit .htaccess by clicking save in that section, therefore if you get an error; contact your hosting provider.

You may also want to check that the URL of your site corresponds to the URLs shown inside of WP > Settings > General.

Answer (score 0):

First ensure your server support rewrite_ module 
1.Login your WordPress dashboard 
2. Click Settings
3.click Permalinks and change your permalink then click save